# Obtain word using the POS tags?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm learning to use the CoreNLP and I'd like to know, is there a way to obtain the word using the POS tag. Let me give an example,

Assume the NLP is asked to POS tag "This is basic testing." and the result is,

```
This_DT is_VBZ basic_JJ testing_NN ._.
```

From it, is there way to obtain just the DT's of the sentence and so on? Other than using basic string commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code demonstrating accessing annotations:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;


public class PipelineExample {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        String text = "This is basic testing.";
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("text: "+text);
        for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                System.out.print("["+token.word()+" "+token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class)+"]");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```